# jQuery UI Dialog buttons within an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, if-statement, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following function, which brings up a menu of fish that can be bought within

```
.dialog({
    title: "Fish Store",
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Beard Fish($30)": function() {
            if (cash >= 30)
            {
                fish1 =1;
                fish1Swim1();
                cash -= 30;
                setNav();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
            else
            {
                notEnoughCash();
            }
        },
        "Clown Fish($50)": function() {
            if (cash >= 50) 
            {
                fish2 = 1;
                fish2Swim1();
                cash -= 50;
                setNav();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
            else 
            {
                notEnoughCash(); 
            }
        },
        "Neon Fish($75)": function() {
            if (cash >= 75) 
            {
                fish3 = 1;
                fish3Swim1();
                cash -= 75;
                setNav();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
            else
            { 
                notEnoughCash(); 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I want to edit the function so that buttons can be turned on and off based on if variables (fish1, fish2, & fish3).

So I try to make the following change...

```
buttons: { 
    if(fish1=0)
    {
        "Beard Fish($30)": function() {
            if (cash >= 30) 
            {
                fish1 =1;
                fish1Swim1();
                cash -= 30;
                setNav();
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
            else 
            { 
                notEnoughCash(); 
            }
        },
   }
```

but my text-edit says the syntax is invalid, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the good aproach is to:

1. Create your dialog box without buttons
2. Add the buttons that you want acc. to your conditions using the [JQueryUI setter](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-buttons)

`$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "buttons", { "Ok": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } } );`

And step 3 :Display your dialog box

Comment: What is JQueryUI setter? Your link doesn't seem to mention the term at all.

Comment: Go to Options->Buttons at the bottom of the page

Comment: Isn't that the exact the same thing I'm already doing in the function I posted?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can't add conditional in the object declaration (between {}). So my idea is to add your buttons dynamically according to your conditions